# How to solve the following equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

```
7 -  a - 4b - ax = 0
8 - 2a - 5b + bx = 0
9 - 3a - 6b -  x = 0
```

I just have to find the value of `x`.

What is the fastest algorithm to solve a problem of the above given template with possibly different constants and co-efficients. The template will always remain the same. Eg: if n=4(here n=3), then I would get an extra column of constant `c` and an extra equation too.

`x` might have `1` to `n` number of solutions depending on the equations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are a,b,c constants and x is the variable you are solving for? It would help to show the other case you want to handle as well.

Comment: a,b,c and x all are variables. But I just want x. Here number of variables = number of equations.

Comment: OK, the first equation: $7 -  a - 4b - ax=0$ suggests that $x=(7-a-4b)/a$ - What more to do? All the other equations would be redundant.

Comment: a and b are variables too. I can't use x=(7-a-4b)/a because I don't know the values of a and b. I want to give x a number, possibly up to n numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is not a Linear System because of the existence of $ax$ and $bx$ in equations $1$ and $2$. However, we will try [Gaussian_elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).
Note: you will need to scroll to see the rest of the answer...

```
The system (where a,b and x) are all variables:
        7 -  a - 4b - ax = 0
        8 - 2a - 5b + bx = 0
        9 - 3a - 6b -  x = 0

        Can be written as:
        a +  4b + ax = 7
        2a + 5b - bx = 8
        3a + 6b +  x = 9          

        -2 X Eqn (1):
        -2a - 8b - 2ax = -14

        Add to Eqn (2) to get the system:
        a +  4b + ax     = 7
        0 -  3b - bx-2ax = 8-14=-6
        3a + 6b +  x     = 9

        -3 X Eqn (1):
        -3a - 12b -3ax = -21

        Add to Eqn (3) to get the system:
        a +  4b + ax     = 7
        0 -  3b - bx-2ax = -6
        0 -  6b + x -3ax  = 9-21=-12

        -2 X Eqn(2) above:

        0 + 6b + 2(bx+2ax) = 12

        Add this to Eqn(3) above to get the system:
        a +  4b + ax     = 7
        0 -  3b - bx-2ax = -6
        0 +  0  + -3ax+2bx+4ax=-12+12-0

        Simplify 3rd equation to get the system:
        a +  4b + ax     = 7
        0 -  3b - bx-2ax = -6
        0 +  0  + ax+2bx= 0

    The last equation suggests that:
    Either x=0 and/or a+2b=0.

    Case-1 for x=0:
    ================
        The original system becomes

        Can be written as:
        a +  4b  = 7
        2a + 5b  = 8
        3a + 6b  = 9

        We have here 3 equations and 2 variables. At least one may be assumed redundant.

        We can use the first 2 equations to get a,b:
        a +  4b  = 7
        2a + 5b  = 8

       Multiply Eqn(1) by (-2) to get: 
        -2a - 8b = -14

     To be reduced to:

        -3b = -6
        so, b=2

        hence a=7-4b that is:
        a=7-8=-1

        So we get:

        x=0, a=-1 and b=2.

    Case-2 for a=-2b:
    =================
    Maybe you can complete this one.
```

**Note:**

If you write the system as:

```
A -  a - 4b - ax = 0
B - 2a - 5b + bx = 0
C - 3a - 6b -  x = 0,
```

you could follow the same process and get a general result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what if I didn't get a 0 in the equation ax+2bx=0 and instead got a constant ax+2bx=constant.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't get your point. Please give a complete example.

Comment: Just as one example, the same method can't be applied if I exchange the constant terms(7 and 8) of the first 2 equations, keeping the rest of the system same.

Comment: The same exact method could be applied. The numbers will change though. See my not at the end of the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: With $$x=9-3a-6b$$ you will get the equations
$$8-2a-5b+b(9-3a-6b)=0$$ and
$$7-a-4b-a(9-3a-6b)=0$$
and we get
$$-2a-3ab-14b-6b^2+8=0$$
$$7-10a+9ab-4b=0$$

Comment: I could use that but that would just change my 3 equations with 2 non-linear terms to 2 equations with 4 non-linear terms. There is a pattern in those equations and I hoping to exploit that somehow for a fast algorithm, if possible.